# Re-write loop to assign a number to every row in a column

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I have a column titled `CompanyNam` and I need to extract the ownership information. The column is in a QGIS attribute table, but that is not important. The column looks like the attached picture.

[image]

For example, if `CEZ` is the first company then, I assign to it number 1, then `Sokolovska` is the next number, etc. If `CEZ` appears again in some other row, it will get number 1. It is important to note that if I have `NULL` in the column I assign a different number to every NULL row entry. I need the numbers corresponding to the `CompanyNam` output. I have the following code:

```
EmptyArray = []
d = {}
newlist = []
for gFeat in GeneratorLayer.getFeatures():
    Owner = gFeat.attributes()[gProvider.fieldNameIndex('CompanyNam')].toString()
    A = ([str(i) for i in Owner]) #convert from PyQt4.QtCore.QString to normal string
    B = ''.join(A)
    EmptyArray.append(B)
    for m, n in enumerate(EmptyArray):
        if n not in d:
            d[n] = [m+1]
        newlist.append({n: d[n]})
        if n == '':
            d[n] = [m+1]
        newlist.append({n: d[n]}) #Every NULL gets a new number
    for names in newlist:
        for o, p in names.iteritems():
            if o == '':
                a2 = str('{},NULL'.format(p))
            elif o != '':
                a2 = str('{},{}'.format(p,o))
```

I then use `a2` in further steps. The code runs fine for a column with 60-100 rows but for larger columns, the computational times are really high. Can you suggest any way in which I can re-write this code, keeping the logic?
The output looks like this:

```
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[9],Sokolovska
[10],International
[11],ENERGOTRANS,
[12],Alpiq
[13],Mittal Steel
[14],United
[1],CEZ
[1],CEZ
[17],Dalkia.....
```

It would be even nicer to have the numbering `[1 ], [2], [3]` and not `[1 ], [9], [10]`, but I haven't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a list, as you do to attach items, and a separate dictionary to get the numbers:

```
EmptyArray = []
d = {}
newlist = []

for gFeat in GeneratorLayer.getFeatures():

    Owner = gFeat.attributes()[gProvider.fieldNameIndex('CompanyNam')].toString()

    A = ([str(i) for i in Owner]) #convert from PyQt4.QtCore.QString to normal string
    B = ''.join(A)

    EmptyArray.append(B)
    
    m = 1

    for n in EmptyArray:  # no need to enumerate as numbers should increment only on uniques

        if n not in d:  # this is a unique
            d[n] = [m]  # put number in dictionary, with key as val.
            m += 1  # so increment

        elif n == '':  # if it's blank (and if it is already in the dict)
            d[n].append(m)  # append new number, as blanks always increment
            m += 1  # increment

    for name in EmptyArray:  # looping less as only want to get names

        if name == '':  # if it's a blank, we want to pop out the first item in the list.
            a2 = str('{},NULL'.format(d[name].pop(0)))

        else:  # otherwise we just index the first item.
            a2 = str('{},{}'.format(d[name][0], name))
```

The above should work.

This way you don't have to loop so much and the logic is a bit clearer. This should hopefully help with computation time, but would also give you the right numbers.

We always append to a list when looping through the EmptyArray, which may not be the best way to go about it, as you only really need a list for the blanks and directly accessing an item without using a list would be faster - but when the list is 1 item long I doubt there will be much difference.

For the blanks we need to use a list, so it can accept multiple numbers (one for each blank). To get the right number for each blank, we just need to pop out the number from the front of the list each time we encounter a blank - which should correspond to the number that was originally assigned to that blank.

We also don't need to make a new list and can just repeat our loop over EmptyArray.

## To make it even more efficient

we can get rid of the second loop over EmptyArray completely (I don't see any extra logic that makes it necessary) and simply do the below with the first loop:

```
    for n in EmptyArray:  # no need to enumerate as numbers should increment only on uniques

        if n == '' :  # blanks always increment - no need to store as we treat them as new
            a2 = str('{},NULL'.format(m))
            m += 1  # so increment

        elif n not in d:  # this is unique, so add to dict and increment
            d[n] = m  # add to dict for future reference
            a2 = str('{},{}'.format(m, n))
            m += 1  # increment

        else:  # it's in the dict, and not a blank, so grab from dict.
            a2 = str('{},{}'.format(d[n], n))
```

That way we have got rid of a large number of the loops and the efficiency of the program should be much improved. It also removes the need to store the blanks corresponding numbers, so that extra effort is saved - and we can use direct references to the numbers for everything else.

## So I made two functions to try and replicate what you want:

```
EmptyArray = ['',1,2,3,'',1,'',3,2,'',1]
m = 1
a2 = ''

def f1 (EmptyArray, d, m, a2):
    for n in EmptyArray:  # no need to enumerate as numbers should increment only on uniques

        if n not in d:  # this is a unique
            d[n] = [m]  # put number in dictionary, with key as val.
            m += 1  # so increment

        elif n == '':  # if it's blank (and if it is already in the dict)
            d[n].append(m)  # append new number, as blanks always increment
            m += 1  # increment

    for name in EmptyArray:  # looping less as only want to get names

        if name == '':  # if it's a blank, we want to pop out the first item in the list.
            a2 += str('{},NULL\n'.format(d[name].pop(0)))

        else:  # otherwise we just index the first item.
            a2 += str('{},{}\n'.format(d[name][0], name))

    print(a2)

def f2 (EmptyArray, d, m, a2):
    for n in EmptyArray:  # no need to enumerate as numbers should increment only on uniques

        if n == '' :  # blanks always increment - no need to store as we treat them as new
            a2 += str('{},NULL\n'.format(m))
            m += 1  # so increment

        elif n not in d:  # this is unique, so add to dict and increment
            d[n] = m  # add to dict for future reference
            a2 += str('{},{}\n'.format(m, n))
            m += 1  # increment

        else:  # it's in the dict, and not a blank, so grab from dict.
            a2 += str('{},{}\n'.format(d[n], n))

    print(a2)

f1(EmptyArray, {}, m, a2)
f2(EmptyArray, {}, m, a2)
```

here is the output for the calls:

```
1,NULL
2,1
3,2
4,3
5,NULL
2,1
6,NULL
4,3
3,2
7,NULL
2,1

1,NULL
2,1
3,2
4,3
5,NULL
2,1
6,NULL
4,3
3,2
7,NULL
2,1
```

and the times for f1 and f2 respectively:

```
3.4341892885662415e-05
1.5789376039385022e-05
```

So f2 takes a bit less than half the time as f1.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I just implemented it but I get an error in this line:  a2 = str('{},NULL'.format(d[name].pop(0)))  It says: IndexError: pop from empty list

Comment: @EliDimitrova, try the solution I posted at the bottom, which replaces both of the last two loops. It should work best. I'll look at why the IndexError occured.

Comment: The code works, I substituted name in the last line with n, but when I look at the output, it gives: 1,Sokolovska which is wrong, it should be 2, Sokolovska. The first time I get 2, something is at the first NULL

Comment: @EliDimitrova not sure why it is going wrong for you, if you see the above example it is giving me the pergect output. what is it giving for CEZ?